# why virtual memory allocation is far higher than resident memory allocation for interpreted languages

Tags: memory

I noticed this for many languages, including

- C#
- Java
- Python
- JS

and many other languages that are being interpreted by some interpreter (and which usually has a garbage collector).

When I check a memory usage on a system (unix) - any system (I tried this on many different servers). I can see a huge difference between allocated virtual memory and resident memory (the real physical memory that is actually being eaten).

This is not a case of languages like c or c++.

For example, a java application that uses 30mb of resident memory can use like 2gb of virtual memory, and this happens for other interpreted languages as well. Of course this doesn't happen everytime (the difference is not so huge in all cases) but in most cases it is rather big.

Or sample (this is actually real data)
a c# application MonoDevelop using 136MB of resident memory but 1661MB of virtual memory

There are also exceptions for robust c++ applications, for example firefox seems to have a same problem, and as far as I know it uses garbage collector as well

This is a problem for every system that restricts memory based on virtual memory (which is actually a correct way, because OS should guarantee that the amout of virtual memory which has been allocated to a process will be actually available for that process).

Why is that?

Comment: Among other things, it depends on how much library code is pulled in.

Answer (score 0):

Your citation of 30 MB virtual translating to 2 GB of virtual isn't a universal law.

I'm used to Java applications that are deployed to a Java EE container (e.g. JBOSS).  The container is an application unto itself.  It loads lots of JARs into resident memory, off heap.  The entire JAR is loaded, not just the few classes that are required.  All of these contribute to total resident memory.

There are other contributions to total resident memory as well.  For example, every thread created gets ~1 MB of memory for its thread stack.  As a result, multi-threaded code will take up more memory.

Most C/C++ apps are compiled to .exe and run on their own, under the OS control.  There's no virtual machine to take into account, so that will always be in their favor.   That's true for all the VM-based languages you cite.

Perhaps it's less common for them to be multi-threaded, so they're missing that contribution.  Linking shared libraries is different from loading JARs.

I think all these factors might explain the difference.

Comment: Yes you are correct, this is not a case of /every/ process, BUT most of them, indeed eat a lot more vmem than the resident memory is...

Comment: I would say that total resident memory > heap memory *by definition*.  It's not a surprise.  The amount by which it exceeds heap differs from app to app.